# PTC Thingworx: java null pointer exception

Tags: java, postgresql, thingworx

TW 6.5.5 with postgres properly configured, after proper deploying of war file, provide a java null pointer exception.
It seems tied to improper credentials (check application.log below) but also folow instructions retrieved on the web to manage the modelprovideconfig.json file, still no chance to have it working properly.
Any idea?

```
016-02-04 11:36:36.372-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] OS: Windows Server 2012
2016-02-04 11:36:36.372-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] OS arch: amd64
2016-02-04 11:36:36.372-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] OS version: 6.2
2016-02-04 11:36:36.372-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] Total Processors: 2
2016-02-04 11:36:36.373-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] Default encoding: UTF-8
2016-02-04 11:36:36.373-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] JAVA vendor: Oracle Corporation
2016-02-04 11:36:36.373-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] JAVA version: 1.8.0_66
2016-02-04 11:36:36.373-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] JAVA install location: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66
2016-02-04 11:36:36.374-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] JVM Max Memory: 495 (MB)
2016-02-04 11:36:36.374-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] ========================================
2016-02-04 11:36:36.374-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] WebApp starting...
2016-02-04 11:36:37.533-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxPersistenceHandler] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] Default Persistence Provider Name = ThingworxPersistenceProvider
2016-02-04 11:36:37.534-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxPersistenceHandler] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] Default Persistence Provider Package Name = PostgresPersistenceProviderPackage
2016-02-04 11:36:37.585-0500 [L: INFO] [O: c.t.p.p.PostgresDatasource] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] Reading configuration from configTableCol
2016-02-04 11:36:38.102-0500 [L: ERROR] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] *** CRITICAL ERROR ON STARTUP: Improper value found for model provider configuration password, system cannot start without valid password
2016-02-04 11:36:38.102-0500 [L: ERROR] [O: c.t.s.ThingWorxBootstrapper] [I: ] [U: SuperUser] [S: ] [T: localhost-startStop-1] *** Web Application STATE is being set to ERROR! ***
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: thanks Soora: nothing programmed right there. Had a look on the suggested topic but no chance to retrieve a possible connection to mu problem. This is for sure related to some credentials issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
Postgresql can only be installed under windows drive (c:): on a different case (other local drive) installation fails.
Also apache/tomcat (and so my webapp at the end) must belong to the same disk (this is causing the java nullpointer exception). A possible alternative is to integrate fixed code into the apache/tomca server.xml config.xml files in ordero to embed for ALL apache/tomcat webapplication credentials.
Since my webapp is pointing to a .json file and refers to a postgresql instance, no chance except putting it into local rrive :-)
that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in your stack trace. You are trying to do something you need password. You are doing something that will normal user don’t and it can make errors all around your system, because password required isn’t often.